# ReactJS: How to update state while scrolling page

Tags: reactjs

I have created a function to detect scroll status, means if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page then 'console.log(true)' and setting state. The function name is handleScroll and I am calling that function from helper file. And in my view file, I'm calling event listener to detect scroll change using the handleScroll function inside componentDidMount & later removing event listener by unmounting.

However, when I run the code initially state is set inside 'atBottom: false'. But later if I scroll down the page the function is not called again and I can't detect whether I am bottom of the page or not.

```
----> View file
import { handleScroll } from 'components/Helper.jsx'


class ScrollStatus extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      height: window.innerHeight,
      scrollBottomStatus: false,
    }
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll(this, 
    this.stateHandler));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll(this, 
    this.stateHandler));
  }

  stateHandler = (state) => {
    this.setState(state);
  }
  render() {
    return ( <div> Long text ... </div> ) }
}
export default ScrollStatus


----> helper file
export const handleScroll = (obj, stateHandler) => {
  const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : 
  document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  const body = document.body;
  const html = document.documentElement;
  const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
  const windowBottom = Math.round(windowHeight + window.pageYOffset);
  if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
    console.log(true)
    stateHandler({
      scrollBottomStatus: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log(false)
    stateHandler({
      scrollBottomStatus: false
    });
  }
}
```

I want the function to keeping checking window height as I scroll down or up and keep updating the state 'isBottom' while scrolling.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

When I check scrolling I always add a throttle (via lodash or ...) to throttle down the actions.

What I would do in your case.

*1. Add eventlistener on mount, also remove on unmount.*

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => _.throttle(this.handleScroll, 100));
  }
```

*2. In the same component I'd handle the state update.*

```
handleScroll = () => {
  let scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
  if(scrollY < 100) { this.setState({ // BLA }) 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mario ... I added throttle function to test it. But my state is not updating as I scroll.  I got error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at later (underscore.js:927)".
I believe _.throttle doesn't seem to be the full proof solution to the tracking of scrolling status.
Also, I am trying to make my handleScroll function modular. Can you please check my code and tell me why is my code only running once.

Comment: this.handleClick needs to be with an arrow function, otherwise the context gets lost. updated.